# Understanding spring proxying

Tags: java, spring, proxy

[The Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-scopes-other-injection) provides the following example to show us the reason why we need to define aop:scoped-proxy explicitly in beans of scope session, reques, etc.

```
<bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" scope="session">
    <aop:scoped-proxy/>
</bean>
<bean id="userManager" class="com.foo.UserManager">
    <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>
</bean>
```

We need proxy here, because for each request to the `userPreferences` bean we want to delegate one to the actual session-scoped bean's instance. That's clear. But the documentation also said that this's a deafult behavior for `singletone/prototype` scoped beans.

Consider the following example:

```
<bean id="userPreferences" class="com.foo.UserPreferences" />
<bean id="userManager" class="com.foo.UserManager">
    <property name="userPreferences" ref="userPreferences"/>
</bean>
```

Why do we need in proxy in the case of `singletone`-scoped beans? Doesn't injecting and calling to proxy cause some performance overhead?

***Question***: For performance sakes, could we avoid injecting proxy and inject actual bean instances in the case of the `singletone`-scoped beans instead?

Comment: Your understanding is wrong. When using singleton scope you get a bean instance not a proxy (at least if you don't use any further AOP like transactions). The same for prototype scope, which could still be a scoped-proxy and each method call would lead to a new instance of that bean.

Comment: @M.Deinum But the documentation said that __You do not need to use the <aop:scoped-proxy/> in conjunction with beans that are scoped as singletons or prototypes..__

Comment: Correct as that generally makes no sense at all. But that does not mean that that is the default behavior...

Comment: @M.Deinum I also have seen proxy instances for singleton beans in a debugger. The beans were singlenton beans and injected into a controller.

Comment: @M.Deinum Actually I've never seen that Spring injected the actual object intance, not a proxy.

Comment: Spring uses proxy based AOP. So if you specify transactions (for instance) you get a proxy. If you have `@Async` you get a proxy. The fact that it it a proxy doesn't mean it is a **scoped** proxy!.

Comment: @M.Deinum But what's the difference between them? Maybe you can get a reference to the documentation explaining it? In general, is it possbile to inject actual object instance, not a proxy?

Comment: As stated if you don't use anything that forces proxy creation you will get a plain instance. If you use transaction or something like that you will always get a proxy (else you wouldn't have transactions). A proxy is a proxy there is no difference, the scoped proxies have a different interceptors applied to them (to lookup the actual instance from the correct scope which is delegated to a `Scope` implementation).